# Compraring Char array without using strcmp in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Im looking for a way to compare 2 char arrays without strcmp. 
Is this the way to go? Or am I missing something? WHen I compiled it, if I type in the same strings in both, the program gets stuck and wont do anything. PLEASE HELP!

EDIT: SORRY IT WAS MEANT TO BE A i not a C

```
int compare_info(char *array1, char *array2)
{

int i;
i = 0;

while(array1[i] == array2[i])
{
    if(array1[i] == '\0' || array2[i] == '\0')
        break;
    i++;
}

if(array1[i] == '\0' && array2[i] == '\0')
return 0;

else
    return-1;

}
```

Comment: The problem is `c++`. Har har.

Comment: Your first `while` is an infinite loop. You compare `array1[i]` and `array2[i]`, but then `i` never changes inside the loop.

Comment: Where do you define the `c` variable?

Comment: When you compile it? your code does not compile.

Comment: `strcmp()` returns a negative value if the first argument sorts low compared to the second, a positive value if the first argument sorts high compared to the second, and zero if they are equal.  Your comparison returns either 0 (correctly) or -1 (not always correctly).

Comment: Here is the thing:

array2 has predetermined "option1"
I input a word into array1 and compare, if this are equal then fine return they are equal if not, return not equal.

Comment: with `i++` the functions works OK. Was that your only problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a solution, is prety like your code, but I have made some changes. I took out the returns in the middle of the loop, because they break the structure, in this way it is easier to analyze. Finishing, I added a new condition to the while, so when the end of string is found, the loop ends

```
int compare_info(char *array1, char *array2)
{
    int i;
    int response = 0;
    i = 0;

    while(array1[i] == array2[i] && response == 0 )
    {
        if(array1[i] == '\0' || array2[i] == '\0'){
            response = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a solution

```
int compare_info(char *array1, char *array2)
{
    if ((array1 == NULL) || (array2 == NULL))
        return 0;
    while ((*array1 != '\0') && (*array2 != '\0') && (*array1 == *array2))
    {
        array1++;
        array2++;
    }
    return (*array1 == *array2);
}
```

or perhaps you like this more

```
int compare_info(char *array1, char *array2)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    if ((array1 == NULL) || (array2 == NULL))
        return 0;
    while ((array1[i] != '\0') && (array2[i] != '\0') && (array1[i] == array2[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
    return (array1[i] == array2[i]);
}
```

you can make the arguments `const` it would be better style since if you only want to compare the strings, you guarantee that the function wont modify them i mean `compare_info(const char *array1, const char *array2)`

Comment: `strcmp()` returns a negative value if the first argument sorts low compared to the second, a positive value if the first argument sorts high compared to the second, and zero if they are equal.  Your comparison returns either 0 (correctly) or -1 (not always correctly).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler He did not say he wants to emulate `strcmp`, he just wants two compare the to strings, this will return `0` when the strings don't match, and non-zero otherwise, it would be easy to transform this functions to return a value like `strcmp` does, but i think this answer addresses the problem, of course, I might just be wrong.

Comment: the initial checks for NULL parameters result in the function returning 'true' (usually defined as 'not false' or 0x01 or 0x02)  This could be very misleading to the calling program and is (probably) not correct if only one of the array pointers contains null and is definitely not correct of both array pointers contains NULL

Comment: @user3629249 I fixed. But I think I still deserve the downvote. Since I didn't think this through.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, I would add the following to the mix as a `strcmp` look-alike without `strcmp`:

```
int strcmp_nohdr (char *s1, char *s2)
{
    if (!s1 && !s2) return 0;
    if (s1 && !s2) return 1;
    if (!s1 && s2) return -1;

    while (*s1 && *s2 && *s1 == *s2) s1++, s2++;

    if (!*s1 && !*s2) return 0;
    else if (*s1 > *s2) return 1;
    else return -1;
}
```

**examples/output:**

```
$ strcmp_nohdr mydog mycat

 s1 is greater than s2

$ strcmp_nohdr mybat mycat

 s1 is less than s2

$ strcmp_nohdr mycat mycat

 s1 is equal to s2

$ strcmp_nohdr mycat myca

 s1 is greater than s2

$ strcmp_nohdr myca mycat

 s1 is less than s2
```

A further alternative would be to call and assembly routine that does the same thing.

Comment: `strcmp_nohdr(NULL, NULL)` will crash things, right? Not that anybody would be silly enough to do that... :-)

Comment: Can you explain me this code? :S can't quite get what you are saying here.

Comment: @Silvestrini The code shown works exactly like `strcmp` (except `ptr > NULL` is considered true in this code if `ptr` is not `NULL`).

Comment: @ChronoKitsune it looks like you confirmed that `NULL,NULL` was covered in `if (!*s1 && !*s2) return 0;` That is the first statement executed in that case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Perhaps you misunderstood what I meant. Both `s1 && !s2` and `!s1 && s2` are false when `s1` and `s2` are both `NULL`. As a result, the code continues with the `while` loop condition. Since both pointers are `NULL`, you accidentally dereference a `NULL` pointer in your `while` loop, which can cause a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some people, I tend to prefer catching null pointers as early as possible (via program crash and a debugger), so I avoid any checks for null pointers below. In other words, don't pass a null pointer to these functions.

The `str_neq` function determines whether the strings are not equal, which seems to be the correct logic based upon your code (return 0/false if equal and -1/true if not equal):

```
int
str_neq (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  while (*s1 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2)
    ++s1, ++s2;
  return -(*s1 != *s2);
}
```

To provide the same behavior as `strcmp` requires a small change in the expression that computes the return value:

```
int
str_compare (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  while (*s1 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2)
    ++s1, ++s2;
  return *s1 - *s2;
}
```

I hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Just personal preference, but you may have another reason why -- `while (*s1 != '\0' ...` isn't just simply `while (*s1 ...` When the pointer is advanced to the null terminator, both tests are equivalent. Any reason you prefer the longer version?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I prefer the shorter version, but I opted for the longer version for clarity. The op seems more comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly:

```
int compare_info(char * array1, char * array2)
{
    char * ptr1 = array1;
    char * ptr2 = array2;

    while(*ptr1 && *ptr2 && *ptr1++==*ptr2++);
    if(!*ptr1 && !*ptr2 && *(ptr1-1)==*(ptr2-1)) return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

When two arrays is same return 0, else return -1. (It's not equal with strcmp.)

Answer (score 0):

The following function should mimic the exact behavior of `strcmp`:

```
int compare_info(const char* array1,const char* array2)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; array1[i]!=0 && array2[i]!=0; i++)
    {
        if (array1[i] > array2[i])
            return +1;
        if (array1[i] < array2[i])
            return -1;
    }
    if (array1[i] != 0)
        return +1;
    if (array2[i] != 0)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```